# Maven . Deploy on Nexus. Still tries to find new new dep in the nexus repo

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I got local Nexus server where we store our deps. 
I want to update some of the existing lib and deploy it to the Nexus.

I set new version by:

```
mvn versions:set -DgenerateBackupPoms=false
```

in my project folder.

say, I set it to be version 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT

then:

```
 mvn clean
```

I see:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://nexus.mycompany.com/repository/maven-public/com/mycompany/bom/0.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://nexus.mycompany.com/repository/maven-public/com/mycompany/bom/0.0.2-SNAPSHOT/bom-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

It can not find the 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT, because there is no such dep there, but why does it try to find it at first place?

Sure it happens for the:

```
mvn deploy
```

Hm.. how can I deploy if it always tries to resolve it in the nexus repo?

Am I missing something?